# Extract Directory from Log File with sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm trying to parse through an application.log that has many lines that follow the same syntax below.

```
"Error","jrpp-237","10/13/11","02:55:04",,"File not found: /indexUsa~.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: c:\websites\pj7fe4\indexUsa~.cfm '' "
```

I need to use some type of command to pull out what is listed between `c:\websites\` and the next `\`

e.g. in this case it would be `pj7fe4`

I thought that the following command would work..

```
bin/sed -n '/c:\\websites\\/,/\\/p' upload/test.log
```

Unfortunately from reading further I now understand that this will return the entire line containing `c:\websites` through the `\` and I need to know the in between, not the whole line.

To be more difficult I need to match all of the directory sub paths, not just one particular line as this is for multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

You're using range patterns incorrectly. You can't use it to limit the command (print in this case) to a part of the line, only to a range of lines. You also don't escape the backspaces.

Try this: `sed 's/.*c:\\websites\\\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\\.*/\1/'`

There's a good sed tutorial here: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

grep way:

```
grep -Po "(?<=c:\\\websites\\\)[^\\\]+(?=\\\)" yourFile
```

test:

```
kent$  echo '"Error","jrpp-237","10/13/11","02:55:04",,"File not found: /indexUsa~.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: c:\websites\pj7fe4\indexUsa~.cfm '' "'|grep -Po "(?<=c:\\\websites\\\)[^\\\]+(?=\\\)"
pj7fe4
```